# How to upload Xcode Project including CocoaPods to the App Store

Tags: xcode, cocoapods

I use CocoaPods in my Xcode Project and want to now how to upload my Xcode Project to the App Store. Before using CocoaPods it was just uploading the Xcode Project but now there is the Xcode Workspace. Should I upload the Workspace or only the Project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have Cocoapods running in your project, you should always use the `.xcworkspace`. This goes for opening your application to edit the code all the way though to deploying your application.

You build, run and archive it just like you would a single project.

Comment: Thanks, that helped!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Xcode to upload the project, archive it as usual, and if you choose to upload to the AppStore it will upload it with the CocoaPods.